# How do I set up a virtual-mapping to a resource on a remote server in the built-in webserver?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, jrun

Our live setup uses IIS and virtual directories to access things like images or pdfs stored on a another server. We are trying to set-up something similar using the built-in webserver with the development edition of CF9.

So far I can successfully use cfdirectory to dump what files are on that remote source, which I had to make the CF9 app server log-on as me to do.

I can copy the folder from the remote server to my local PC and add a virtual-mapping entry to jrun-web.xml and that works fine, though this is not ideal for our purposes.

```
<virtual-mapping>
  <resource-path>/login/images/directory/*</resource-path>
  <system-path>C:/Users/[MyUserName]/Desktop/directory</system-path> 
</virtual-mapping>
```

However I cannot map directly to that remote server.
I tried

```
<virtual-mapping>
  <resource-path>/login/images/directory/*</resource-path>
  <system-path>\\[remoteServer]\images\directory</system-path> 
</virtual-mapping>
```

And

```
<virtual-mapping>
  <resource-path>/login/images/directory/*</resource-path>
  <system-path>//[remoteServer]/images/directory</system-path> 
</virtual-mapping>
```

And I tried mapping a network drive

```
<virtual-mapping>
  <resource-path>/login/images/directory/*</resource-path>
  <system-path>Z:/images/directory</system-path> 
</virtual-mapping>
```

All of which result in 404s on anything inside /login/images/directory/

Comment: Any reason why you don't use IIS locally?

Comment: No real reason, But I `THOUGHT` it would be easier to just use the built in webserver.

Comment: +1 on using IIS or Apache locally. You will have more options and certainly have more folks who can help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev should mirror production in my opinion.  It avoids going live with indorseen issues.  I would highly recommend using IIS in db as you have in live.

Comment: We're already out of luck there, Live is running Windows 2k3, and IIS 6.something, Since our dev machines are win7, we're using IIS 7.5, which is not an insignificant version difference. I guess it's closer to matching, but still could lead to issues of it working on a dev machine but not on live.

Comment: Even so I would still highly recommend using IIS.

Comment: I would say, "Dev should mirror production as close as possible". IIS 7.5 is closer to IIS 6 than the ColdFusion's built-in web server is to IIS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your Apache server will need to have permissions to this directory. ON a windows box you would run apache as a service with a logon account granted "act as a service" permission.  The logon account would need to have access to the unc path in question (\servername\blah\blah).

I also think you should be using the alias syntax as in

Alias /images //servername/project

you might need to use front slashes or escaped back slashes as well (I can't find my example) like either //server/blah or \\server\blah.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The built-in webserver for developer eddition is a jrun server, not apache. It also seems to run silently, there is no service for it that I can grant permissions to.

Comment: Ah... I missed that you were using the built in web server. Have you tried permissioning the CF service?  It may run in the same context.

Comment: yeah, have the CF service log-on as me, so CF can access the remote server, hence I can query with cfdirectory. The webserver seems to have a different privilege.